# Simple `Assert.IsAssignableFrom<T>` failing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Why does this simple assert statement fail? From what I've read I should be . Unfortunately, since the functionality is so basic there isn't much information out there.

```
public interface IDummy{}
public class Dummy : IDummy {}

Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IDummy>(new Dummy());
```

Running this test yields

```
Expected: assignable from <Application.Tests.ViewModels.IDummy>
  But was:  <Application.Tests.ViewModels.Dummy>
```

I have tried swapping the interface and objects side to no avail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IsAssignableFrom works in reverse from what you are expecting.  It's asking: Is (the value) Assignable From IDummy.  Or: "Is  assignable to (value)?"

From the XML doc:
    /// Asserts that an object may be assigned a  value of a given Type.

You probably want Assert.IsInstanceOfType()

Comment: Ah, that works. Thanks. What's the purpose of `IsAssignableFrom` then?

Comment: @gsco, see my answer below

Answer (score 5):

For the benefit of those who land here through Google (or Bing :-) )

`Assert.IsAssignableFrom<T>(object actual)` is meant to check if the object being examined can be substituted by the type T. Effectively, what this means is that the assertion is testing an "is-a" relationship between the object examined and the type T.

Let's see some code (intentionally simplified):

```
// The Base class
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfJoining { get; set; }
}

// The derived class
public class Manager : Employee
{
    public IList<Employee> EmployeesReporting { get; set; }
}
```

Now the assertion:

```
// NOTE: using Assert = NUnit.Framework.Assert;
[TestMethod]
public void Test_IsAssignableFrom()
{
    var employee = new Employee();

    // Manager is-a Employee, so the below is true
    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<Manager>(employee);    
}
```

Whereas the `IsInstanceOf<T>(object actual)` is meant to check whether the object being tested is (like the name suggests) an instance of type T - simply put, if "actual" is the type T or a type derived from T

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_IsAssignableFrom()
{
    var manager = new Manager();

    // Manager derives from Employee so the below is true
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<Employee>(manager);   
}
```

**EDIT**
Turns out, these asserts work the same way as Type.IsAssignableFrom and Type.IsInstanceOf methods on [System.Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: So, in a PluralSight course by Mark Seeman, he uses xUnit. There's a class defined as `public class SimpleWebToken : IEnumerable<Claim> {...}`. Then, in his xUnit test he has `Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEnumerable<Claim>>(sut)` (where `sut` is an instance of `SimpleWebToken`). And this test passes! But by all accounts, it should fail. When using the exact same assertion with NUnit, the test fails. And, running `var good = SimpleWebToken.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable<Claim>)); // good = false` gives me the expected `false` result. Hmmm, I'm losing confidence in testing frameworks.

Comment: Never mind on this. xUnit is doing something funky, but cool, because it mimics how you use the `System.Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)` method in the BCL. NUnit, on the otherhand, has constraint methods `IsAssignableFrom` and `IsAssignableTo` which are backwards from the BCL. So, when using reflection, you'd use `IsAssignableFrom`, but when writing an assertion in NUnit, you'd use the `Is.AssignableTo<TType>()` constraint. Confusing.

Comment: @fourpastmidnight These days I favour using the wonderful [Shoudly](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly) assertion library where I can simplify the assertion as ```someInstance.ShouldBeOfType<TExtpected>```